# System.InvalidCastException On Server

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Hello there I'm having a problem I can't find a solution, in my laptop everything works fine, but on server it gives me this error: "

**Error message:**

> System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid. at
>   System.Data.DataRowExtensions.UnboxT`1.ValueField(Object value) at
>   System.Data.DataRowExtensions.Field[T](DataRow row, String columnName)
>   at Blue.Adesao.GetAdesoes(SqlConnection conexao, SqlTransaction trans)
>   at listagem_form_obras.GetAdesoes()"

**The function about:**

```
    public static DataTable GetAdesoes ( SqlConnection conexao, SqlTransaction trans ) {
        SqlCommand comando;
        String sql;

        sql = "SELECT id, data_criacao, nome, nif, telefone, email, valido " +
              "FROM forms_adesao_entidade ";
        comando = new SqlCommand(sql, conexao, trans);
        SqlDataAdapter dtadapter = new SqlDataAdapter(comando);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dtadapter.Fill(dt);

        dt.Columns.Add("dataFormatada", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("validacao", System.Type.GetType("System.String")));
        foreach(DataRow r in dt.Rows) {
            int valido = (int)r.Field<int>("valido");
            r["validacao"] = Adesao.GetValidacao(valido, conexao);
            r["dataFormatada"] = Utilidades.FormatarData(r.Field<DateTime>("data_criacao"));
        }
        return dt;
    }

    public static string GetValidacao ( int IDValido, SqlConnection conexao ) {
        string sql = "";
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sql = "SELECT [designacao] FROM [forms_estados] WHERE id=@IDValido";
        SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand(sql, conexao);
        comando.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@IDValido", SqlDbType.Int));
        comando.Parameters["@IDValido"].Value = IDValido;
        SqlDataAdapter dtadapter = new SqlDataAdapter(comando);
        dtadapter.Fill(dt);

        return dt.Rows[0].Field<string>("designacao");
    }
```

Database [image: Database]

in front-end I have a simple gridview.

Comment: Is `data_criacao` null for the row in question?

Comment: Some of your server data is probably null. Do you have two different databases? All the columns that allow nulls have to be checkd if they contain a value before casting.

Comment: no by default every field that is called there has a value, either in db and in insert query just in case something goes wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line `int valido = (int)r.Field<int>("valido");` is causing the error, right?

Your database allows this field to be nullable. So this may be the problem. When you encounter a record with a null-valido, the cast isn't possible.

You could try something like the following:

```
foreach(DataRow r in dt.Rows)
{
    int valido = r.IsNull("valido") ? 0 : r.Field<int>("valido");
    r["validacao"] = Adesao.GetValidacao(valido, conexao);
    r["dataFormatada"] = Utilidades.FormatarData(r.Field<DateTime>("data_criacao"));
}
```

Comment: I bet this is the problem ;-] and the winner is @khlr

Comment: but with this line how do i call the var valido in the next method? because its shows me a error of invalid argument

Comment: still gives me: "System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid. at System.Data.DataRowExtensions.UnboxT`1.NullableField[TElem](Object value) at System.Data.DataRowExtensions.Field[T](DataRow row, String columnName) at Blue.Adesao.GetAdesoes(SqlConnection conexao, SqlTransaction trans) at listagem_form_obras.GetAdesoes()"

Comment: Ok found the problem, the server was not updating my DB with the last version of it, it was using the field valido like a boolean, but thx for this tip @khlr

Answer (score 2):

A decent disassembler is a good way to find out why the code failed.  Mine says:

```
private static T ValueField(object value)
{
    if (DBNull.Value == value)
    {
        throw DataSetUtil.InvalidCast(Strings.DataSetLinq_NonNullableCast(typeof(T).ToString()));
    }
    return (T) value;
}
```

That leaves only one possibility, the column in the table you query contains a null.  Your screenshot of the table design does not exclude that possibility, you allow "valido" to be null.  The exception message should have told you this, be sure you can see it.

Comment: This is the most insightful way to debug the issue, as this would form the basis of what's wrong with the data. Db in itself do some sanity check as it would not allow non int data in the Int field, so the only one which can escape that check is a NULL, certainly when allowed